# Looking for a Laravel passport 'client' usage example

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-passport, oauth2client

I seem to be finding tons of tutorials on setting up laravel with passport, setting up an api/server with passport. Authenticating on that server with oauth. Even setting up a client in the JSON interface.  But after going through pages of google results and stack-overflow questions, I have yet to find an example of 'using a client' set up in laravel with passport.

Can someone either give me a clue and/or point me to a doc as to how you use the client portion of passport in laravel?

I used the artisan commands to create a client to talk to the etsy oauth2 api v3.  They require an additional code_challenge and code_challenge_method field be sent in the initial exchange to get a code.  Then when you get a code, you need to request specific access tokens with a given scope, occasionally requesting a refresh of them.  The tokens are then used to do the individual requests.

```
authorization url: https://www.etsy.com/oauth/connect
query params:
    response_type="code"
    code_challenge_method="S256"
    redirect_uri=(local callback url)
    scope=(list of scopes)
    client_id={clientid}
    state={random nonce}
```

(returns code)

token request:  getAuthorizationUrl(redirectrui,scopes,code,state)

code I already have ready to build the parameters array:

```
    $scope_list = implode(' ', EtsyToken::DEFAULT_SCOPES);
    $params = [
        'response_type'         => EtsyToken::DEFAULT_RESPONSE_TYPE,
        'client_id'             => env('ETSY_APP_KEYSTRING'),
        'redirect_url'          => self::getRedirectUri(),
        'scope'                 => $scope_list,
        'state'                 => $this->_token->state,
        'code_challenge'        => $this->_token->challenge,
        'code_challenge_method' => EtsyToken::CODE_CHALLENGE_METHOD
    ];
```

I've managed to get it working with guzzle in separate (non-laravel)test scripts.  I even have the redirect url ready to catch the results, and a method/model ready to grab and store the token details. I'd like to do it using passport if possible to handle the communication. I understand it might even do much of what I built the token model to do.

Can someone please either direct me to better documentation on using the laravel passport client and/or show me a basic example?

Answer (score 0):

Having had a similar journey, I just don't think there is one.

I've also not seen anything confidently offered as a robust client that "just works" with passport. I suspect it's because passport itself can be so difficult to set up for anything but happy path clean installations like the ones you've seen.

Comment: from what i could see, the 'passport' is more for storing client credentials then creating a client itself.  It looks like it might have been planned but never implemented, and only server-side stuff was built.

Answer (score 0):

Socialite should be used for OIDC clients, they have a provider for Laravel Passport.

https://github.com/SocialiteProviders/Laravel-Passport